# DataGridView column with textbox , plus & minus button sign for Quantity

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, gridview, datagridview

I'm doing this project in ASP.Net (Framework 4.0).

I have binded gridview with database. I have edited gridview & added a Template Field & in item template add 2 button (+ & -) with textbox from toolbox .

My question is that on `btnPlus` or `btnMinus` Click the quantity in textbox would increase or decrease , but i cannot find textbox1.text to display value.

And how should I multiply with quantity in textbox with price in label.?

What is the problem ,what should else method i should try.....?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I solved by my self.
If anybody wants to use this code go thru it.

Instead of using TemplateField Use ButtonField in grid View for btnPlus & btnMinus.

Select GridView_RowCommand for GridView1 and give CommandName to ButtonField for Both.

Code as follow

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
 {
   if (e.CommandName == "btnPlus")
   {
      // Your Logic for Adding & Multiplication
   }
   if (e.CommandName == "btnMinus")
   {
      // Your Logic for Subtraction & Multiplication
   }
 }
```